# pixellib is hanging on aws ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, deep-learning

For object secgmentation process with flask I have using the pixellib library but in AWS EC2 instance (instance type t2 xlarge). but this process is holding at semantic_segmentation(). anyone please support to how to solve this issue or which server need to use?